# Loop over list of tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to loop over a list of tuples 
(e.g. `[('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)]`).

If I try

```
for i,j in list:
    print(list[i] + " | " + list[j])
```

I get a type error saying "list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

How could I fix that, so that my output will be something like:

```
One | 1
Two | 2
Three | 3
```

Comment: `i` and `j` are the _items_ you are looking for. They are not indices. Simply `print(i, "|", j)`.

Comment: That is because `i` is `'One'` and `j` is `1`, etc.., so just `print(i, '|', j)`. Note: don't use `list` as a variable name as it hides python's `list` type and will cause you issues at some point.

Answer (score 4):

```
for i,j in list:
    print(list[i] + " | " + list[j])
```

it should be changed to

```
for i, j in list:
    print(i + " | " + str(j))
```

because i and j are not indices but are the values.

Note that when adding two strings together you are concatenating them, which is usually found as bad practice within the Python community. Each concatenation creates a new string objects that takes up a new memory location, which can slow down a program. Many also argue that concatenation is not very readable because of the leading and trailing space characters that are needed in order to have proper formatting. The most widely used alternative is [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting).

```
for i, j in list:
    print("{} | {}".format(i, j))
```

Also, don't use the built-in names for your variable, in this case `list`, so I'll suggest you to take a different variable:

```
for i, j in list_iterate:
        print("{} | {}".format(i, j)
```

Comment: This will complain that it doesn't know how to concatenate (`+`) a `str` and `int`, either pass them all as args to `print()` or explicitly turn `j` into `str(j)`. And using `list` as a variable name is not a good idea.

Comment: thankyou, and I have mentioned regarding not to use the list as a variable

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
ll = [('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)]

for x, y in ll:
    print(x + " | " + str(y), end=' ')
```

I kept `end` as ' ' as your required output is in a single line

If you don't want that do

```
for x, y in ll:
    print(x + " | " + str(y))
```

You got an error in your code `print(list[i] + " | " + list[j])` because you are using the values in the list to index that very same list.

You got the error `" list indices must be integers or slices, not str"` because you were trying to index `list['One']` in the loop. Which is not valid in python.

Also, as mentioned in the comments do not use keywords as variable names.

Comment: The OP required them on separate lines, they just didn't format their post correctly.

Comment: Edited my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your answer is that `list[i]` is a `str` and `list[j]` is a `int` so both can't be combined in the way you are combining.

I think using a single `iterator` would be enough to solve the problem.

```
tuple_to_iterate = [('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)]
for a_tuple in tuple_to_iterate:
    print (a_tuple[0] + " | " + str(a_tuple[1]))
```

*Hope this answers your question!!!*

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick, you almost had it!

```
x = [('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)]

for i,j in x:
    print(f"{i} | {j}")
```

When you iterate over a list of tuples and assign each iteration multiple values (i and j in this example), you no longer have to deal with the actual tuple, you now have a string (i), and an int (j).

similar to:

```
x = (1, 2)
print(type(x)) # <class 'tuple'>
a, b = x
print(a)       # 1
print(type(a)) # <class 'int'>
print(b)       # 2
print(type(b)) # <class 'int'>
```

without the iteration

Answer (score 0):

```
my_list = [('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)]
for i,j in my_list:
    print(i + " | " + str(j))
```

Another option to format string:

```
for i,j in my_list:
    print("{} | {}".format(i,j))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same thing in a single line using `list comprehension`.

```
nested_list = [('One', 1), ('Two', 2), ('Three', 3)]
print([l[0]+' | '+str(l[1]) for l in nested_list])
```

Output:
`['One | 1', 'Two | 2', 'Three | 3']`

As a single string, 
`print('\n'.join([l[0]+ ' | '+str(l[1]) for l in ll]))`

Output:

```
One | 1 
Two | 2 
Three | 3
```